# Firebase with Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

While trying to connect my flutter application with firebase the app crashes (target device with android version `4.4.2`).

Error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(28035): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.omarhaassaan.chat_app-3.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.omarhaassaan.chat_app-3, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /lib]]
```

What is causing this error?

---

Possible solutions that I could think of:

1. Enabled MultiDex
2. Minify true

Comment: try with flutter clean & again flutter pub get, if you are using minify then try setting minify to false for testing

Comment: after searching a lot, I found that Enabling MultiDex causes the application to crash for android 4.4.2 kitkat, is that true and is there any solution ?

Comment: Well that shouldn’t happen, MultiDex only helps mitigate the 65K method limit. If that limit is hit, the app won’t simply compile as AS will throw an error. This issue seems specifically related to a missing class, maybe a rare occurrence or due to using minify enabled & not having proper Proguard/R8 rules. but use whatever works for you.